# Component type not working with Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager

I have created a Content Type for the PT of my Page based on a Schema and a Component Template.

In Experience Manager when I opt option to create and insert content on the Page then it creates the Component based on the Content Type, but it put that Component with some other Component Template (1st Component Template which is linked to that CT) not the CT used in the Content Type.

I have already configured the PT to use only predefined Content Types and there is only one Content Type.

Please suggest if this is the known bug in Tridion. I am using Tridion 2013-SP1 and working on a DD4T project.

Thanks.
Mukesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just writing this answer to clarify confusion around content type and functionality of create and insert new content of experience manager.

When we create content type in a publication it has schema and CT associate with it with some other value too. When we create component for a webpage using specified content type from experience manager UI by selecting option **create and insert new content** we thought it will add the component with specified CT in content type but that is not actually happened and causes a confusion.

Clarification: Insert always insert the component with first CT it found in CMS. This is clarified by [SDL documentation link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A3EDFFF5-2690-4505-A18F-FD3D12B632F6) and Alvin [blog](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/08/more-on-xpm-regions-difference-between.html). Thanks again to Alvin to clarify this Tridion faulty behavior.

Thanks.
Mukesh

Comment: I would say the behavior might be unclear or unexpected, but it's not wrong or faulty per se. The custom content type will control how new content is added (assuming the Page Template is configured to use it) but adding existing content defaults to the first CT when XPM regions don't dictate otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two possible locations for Content Types. First the Page which you use as a Page Type, can contain so called cloneable Components (you specify in the Page whether to include the current Component Presentation or a copy of it). Secondly you can define Content Types on your Publication, these you can use in the XPM settings and add to a Page via that route.

I'm not really sure, but it sounds to me like you might have both options, so a Component on the Page with the first CT and then in the Publication properties a Content Type using the same Component but with a different CT.

Apparently when you define both, it will use the one on the Page as a preference. If you have no Component Presentations on your Page, then it sounds like a defect indeed.

Comment: Hi Bart, I have Page and content type both in my publication. My content type also have the correct CT(A). But when we opt option to create and insert content it insert the content with wrong CT(B). This wrong CT is 1st CT which have linked schema same as my component schema. 
I think this is the issue with experience manager insert content option.When I created a region on the page and drag the component to region then it insert the component with correct CT. But unfortunately when I remove all the content from page then region disappear and then dragging component cause wrong CT appearing.

Comment: @MukeshKumar the region should be on your Page, not created or related to content being on the Page. But that is besides the point, from that what I have seen myself is that it worked fine when there was a cloneable Component directly on the Page.

Comment: Hi Bart,

Yes, cloneable component with page type is working fine in my case too. Issue appears when I am trying to insert(either by create and insert or by adding existing component) any component from site edit UI. While I am dragging the component inside region, it is working fine and render with CT already used on the page but when there is no component available on page then it is inserting with other CT.
Please suggest if I am missing something..

Comment: @MukeshKumar when you drag and insert it will only follow region directions I think, so if you don't have the region markup specified, it will take the first available CT indeed.

Comment: There *is* a subtle difference in behavior between `Insert` and `Drag-and-drop`. Regions change what we should do. The documentation notes to [not use `Insert` with regions](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A3EDFFF5-2690-4505-A18F-FD3D12B632F6). I figured out [why in this post](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/08/more-on-xpm-regions-difference-between.html). *Without regions*, then the "first template" applies (see [@PeterK's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14157469/395495)).

Comment: Thanks Alvin to clarify the confusion with insert functionality in experience manager UI. Earlier confusion was if we already have ct associated with content type then I thought it should be associated when we choose option of create and insert. I am providing the complete detail around confusion with content type and functionality with experience manager in my answer of this question. Thanks for your help..